# repo has been modified automatically after repo sync

Tags: android, git, repo

On macosx,I use below command to repo sync from google:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.0.0_r4
repo sync frameworks/av
```

Then in frameworks/av, I found one file always modifed:

```
cd frameworks/av/
git status
Not currently on any branch.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   media/libstagefright/include/DataURISource.h

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I can not remove that modified file at all, `git reset --hard` doesn't work.

Comment: Is your macosx case-sensitive? If not, there may be a file of the same name with different capital and small letters. Try `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep -i DataURISource`.

Comment: @ElpieKay you are right, on linux, the file name is DataUriSource.h and DataURISource.h, but on macosx, it's the same name! how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with macosx. But I've learned that it supports both case-sensitive and non-case-sensitive. Maybe you could switch it to case-sensitive. If not this way, you'll have to rename one of the two files and commit the change.